# UIWebView.loading returns false

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

With swift using the following code:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
view.addSubview(webView)

let URL = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))
println(webView.loading)
```

It prints false and the screen is blank. How is this resolved?

Comment: it should print false, loading won't have finished yet... add a delegate and implement the methods

Comment: @Wain `loading` is *false* while the webview is actively loading?

Comment: My bad, that's the wrong way round, but you do need to add a delegate and look at the feedback

Comment: I can only assume that the `println` statement is happening before the webview has actually started loading.  It prints `false` for me as well, but it does end up loading the page.  Implementing a delegate is entirely unnecessary to get it to work.  However, if it's not working, implementing the delegate can help diagnose.  Have you checked the simulator/device's Internet connection?  Can you navigate to Google via Safari on the same device/simulator?

Comment: Thank nhgrif. You are correct, it does eventually load. Is it possible to make a UIWebview not full screen?

Comment: @TebTheestatebook Yes.  You can make it whatever size you want.  That's what the `frame:` argument is for...

Comment: how do you get the frame respect the Mainstoryboard display, I assume code above will default to full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly normal behaviour. The `UIWebView` does not actually start loading content until the UI event, in this case `viewDidLoad`, has finished executing. So checking it immediately returns `false` because it has not started just yet.

If you want want to track the success or failure of the `UIWebView` you should implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` in your view controller. That way you get callbacks when the request has finished loading or if it has failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain exactly on the internals of how `UIWebView` loads its data or what exactly happens when you call `loadRequest`, but contrary to my expectations, nothing seems to actually happen until the method which called `loadRequest` has returned.

Consider the following code:

```
@IBAction func buttonPress(sender: UIButton) {
    let webview = UIWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    view.addSubview(webview)

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    webview.delegate = self
    webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!))
    println("buttonPress: webview.loading? \(webview.loading)")
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    println("webview asking for permission to start loading")
    return true
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    println("webview did start loading")
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError) {
    println("webview did fail load with error: \(error)")
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    println("webview did finish load!")
}
```

Here, the `println` in the `buttonPress` method always executes before any of the other methods.  In fact, seemingly no matter what sort of code we put after the `loadRequest` call, it *all* executes before the web view even asks `shouldStartLoadingWithRequest:`.

```
webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url!))
for _ in 1...10000 {
    println("buttonPress: webview.loading? \(webview.loading)")
}
```

Ten thousand iterations, and yet nothing starts for the webview until after `buttonPress` method returns.

Meanwhile, `webview.loading` will only return `true` between `webViewDidStartLoad` and one of the two ways the load can stop (failure/success) (`webView(webView:didFailLoadWithError:)` or `webViewDidFinishLoad()`).

**IF** you implement the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol and set the web view's delegate, you can implement these methods to keep track of the loading process.  If, for whatever reason, your web view isn't loading the URL, implementing `webView(webView:didFailLoadWithError:)` is the only way to get any sort of diagnostic informatin to determine what failed with the load.